# Concatenar 2 valores en una celda PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Buen día, colegas.

Estoy intentando colocar 2 valores en una celda cuando se genera un reporte con PHPExcel. El detalle está en la línea 9 del siguiente código. Solamente imprime el primer valor ($dato->numero_proyecto), pero también quiero que se imprima el ($dato->nombre_proyecto)

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A{$contador}", $dato->idtbl_bitacora);                
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B{$contador}", $dato->fecha);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C{$contador}", $dato->nombres_user);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D{$contador}", $dato->numero_interno);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("E{$contador}", $dato->nombres);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("F{$contador}", $dato->hora);                
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("G{$contador}", $dato->resguardo);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("H{$contador}", $dato->destino);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("I{$contador}", $dato->numero_proyecto, $dato->nombre_proyecto);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("J{$contador}", $dato->hora_arribo);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("K{$contador}", $dato->estatus);                
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("L{$contador}", $dato->incidencia);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("M{$contador}", $dato->observaciones);
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y si en vez de separar en distintos parámetros el número y el nombre los concatenas? es decir:

```
$dato->numero_proyecto ." " .$dato->nombre_proyecto
```

Comment: Excelente, me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.